# Gupshup whatsApp template message

Tags: templates, gupshup

I am trying to send template message using Gupshup API.

I used the exact same cURL that is mentioned in their documentation.

I received response as:

```json
{ 
messageId: "*******",
status: " submitted "
}
```

But I didn't receive any message on WhatsApp.

How shall I proceed now?

PS: Templates are enabled in my gupshup app, but app is not live yet.